# Confluence | How to create a pop-up dialogue or a landing page where users can insert their names to a box to be stored?

Tags: macros, popup, confluence, confluence-macros

We have a newsletter in our firm's Confluence page. But we send our newsletter to people via e-mail and ask them to access it via a link because their Confluence accounts are not activated. So, I would like to have a pop-up box when they first enter the newsletter and ask them to enter their name if they want to subscribe to the newsletter. Then, their names should be stored so that I can view them later on so the next time we send our newsletter they can be included. But unfortunately I am not very knowledgeable about Confluence, so I would like to ask for your help.

I don't know if pop-ups are possible in Confluence, but at least creating a landing page would work for me. But I would prefer a pop-up dialog, otherwise I would have to make a different page and after entering the name I would have to redirect people to the actual newsletter. But as I said, if pop-ups are not possible, this is not a problem for me.

One last thing, I don't know if I can download user macros since I will be doing within our firm, so I may need to create macros myself. I kindly ask for your help in this sense.

You can see what I am trying to acquire below. When the "Submit" button is pressed, I want to store the name and redirect the user to the newsletter. Thank you so much.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4GdH.png)

Unfortunately I am not very knowledgeable about Confluence. I have tried few things regarding the macros but could not achieve what I had in mind. Also, it seems that there are no related videos or other sources that I could find regarding the subject. So, I kindly ask for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not available out of the box in Confluence, but it is technically possible by creating the necessary macros/apps with Atlassian Java SDK (). You can create them using Atlassian Java SDK (https://developer.atlassian.com/server/) or using some existing 3-rd party solution. All UI kit of Confluence can be customized with such apps.